# my pandas and seaborn comands not responding

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda

import pandas as pd

dataFrame = pd.read_excel("C:/Users/****/desktop/python folder/tensorflow/sheet.xlsx")

import seaborn as sbn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sbn.pairplot(dataFrame)

#### Output is:  PS C:\Users \ -----\Desktop\python folder> & C:/Users/------/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe "c:/Users/-----/Desktop/python folder/tensorflow/tensorflow-101.py"

Comment: I downloaded anaconda 3 days ago and I tried write codes on vsc. but system gived errors about anaconda so I removed anaconda. But this time it is not responding at all.

Comment: Why don't you try your code in jupyter notebook?

Comment: Actually I tried. When I used jupyter it actually worked. But I wanted to use vsc but here we are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your problem, try this.

```py
import seaborn as sbn 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sbn.pairplot(dataFrame)
plt.show()
```

Graph will appear in new window, I guess. It's why your code is working in jupyter, and not in script.

ps. vsc is just a editor, so you can't use vsc for executing python. You are executing python script with your own python program.